# Makelist sort of command in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

In Maxima there's a nice command called [`makelist`](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_5.html).

So for instance, in Maxima:

```
sort ( append ( makelist(0.01*10^i,i,0,3) , makelist(0.03*10^i,i,0,3) ) )
[0.01,0.03,0.1,0.3,1.0,3.0,10.0,30.0]
```

The MATLAB command `linspace` doesn't quite meet my demand.
How could I effortlessly get the above output with a simple command?
The list doesn't need to be sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use colon operator:

```
0.03*10.^(0:3)
```

If you read the documentation of [`linspace`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html), `linspace` is very similar to `:`:

> linspace is similar to the colon operator, “:”, but gives direct control over the number of points and always includes the endpoints.